# Popping ViewController on Swift

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift

I need to pop a UIViewController from the navigation controller.

Just writing this line of code but taking an exception;

unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

If I make the navigation controller optional, this line makes no effect, no popping

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: It seems just too obvious, but are you sure that you access your navigationController correclty? I.e, self.navigationController is not nil?

Answer (score 99):

You need to unwrap your navigationController correctly

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    navController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This basically has the same effect as optional chaining; it works if it's not nil and does nothing if it is.

Comment: This is no different than the question's code in effect.

Answer (score 24):

Swift 3.0
This is working for me

`self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

[image]

Comment: `_ =` is not needed here

Comment: If you are not using return type of variable then you can written like this _ =

Answer (score 9):

In my case im using a Master Details view ( Split View Controller ).
My details view controller is embedded inside an navigation controller. So when i wanted to dismiss my Details view controller. I had to pop it from the navigation controller of the parent (Split view controller)
Like this.

```
_ = self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yes! I needed to get the navigationController of the navigationController!!

Comment: Wow! Works in the case of split view controller. +1

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the view controller you're working with isn't embedded in Navigation Controller. If there was a Navigation Controller, i.e. `self.navigationController` is not nil, both lines should work just as well even though the latter one is preferred as it uses optional chaining.

Make sure you have embedded your View Controller in a Navigation Controller. You can do it by selecting the View Controller in Storyboard editor and clicking *Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller*. Also make sure that you have your *Storyboard Entry Point* (the arrow that indicates which view controller is presented first) either pointing to Navigation Controller or before it.